# Query Performance while using Oracle aggregate function

Tags: performance, oracle, function, aggregate

Below is the query in which I am using an aggregate function. The where clause is simple with an index on corpId and incoming_date .
If I simply fetch all rows/count the query takes lesser than a second. However when I use the aggregate function the query takes about 4 minutes.
I am using oracle 11i and the total rows the where clause retrieves is around 64000.  The table and index statistics have also been gathered recently and there are no new rows added in the table.

Please suggest on improving the speed.

```
SELECT
sum(paid_amt) totalamount
FROM test_table e
WHERE  e.corpId =6
AND e. incoming_date >= to_date('01-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
AND e. incoming _date <= to_date('09-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: What are the two queries that you are running?  In particular, when you aren't using the aggregate function, are you selecting the `paid_amt` column?  What are the two query plans?  Are you saying that it takes less than a second to return the last of the 64,000 rows?  Or are you using a GUI that will display the first few rows before fetching the last row?

Comment: The 2 queries: First one is the one I have already posted and the second is the one that fetches the count(using count(*)). The count gives 64k in less than a second while the sum takes 4 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Include `paid_amt` into the index:

```
CREATE INDEX
        ix_testtable_cord_date_paid
ON      test_table (corpId, incoming_date, paid_amt)
```

If you have an index on just `(corpId, incoming_date)` and try to test speed like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    test_table
WHERE   e.corpId = 6
        AND e.incoming_date >= to_date('01-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
        AND e.incoming_date <= to_date('09-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

you not querying for anything outside the index so the query can be satisfied with an `INDEX (RANGE SCAN)` alone.

As soon as you add anything not in the index (`paid_amt` in your case), the query needs to to use additional `TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID)` to retrieve the record from the table.

It's random lookups in a nested loop and it's slow, especially if your table records are large (have lots of fields or long fields).

The optimizer may even deem this access method less efficient that the `FULL SCAN` and use the latter instead.

Comment: True. Thanks. I am creating the composite index on (corpId, incoming_date, paid_amt). The table has 319,332,896 records. So the index creation is going to take some time. Will post an update after the index is created.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked well. The sum takes 0.1sec. What if I changed my query to the one below:

Comment: SELECT NVL(SUM(paid_amt),0) paidAmount,
    NVL(SUM(cust_served),0) totalCustServed,
    NVL(SUM(BILLED_AMT,0)) billedAmt,
    NVL(SUM(e.tax_paid,0)) taxPaid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cust_name) custName,
    NVL(SUM(bal_Payment,0)) balPayment,
    NVL(SUM(adv_payment,0)) advPayment
    FROM test_table e
    WHERE 1=1
    AND e.corp_id =92
    AND e.incoming_date >= '02-Aug-2012'
    AND e.incoming__date <= '09-Jan-2013'

Comment: Will the below index work?
    CREATE INDEX TT_PAID_IDX 
 ON  test_table corp_id,incoming_date,paid_amt,cust_served, 
        BILLED_AMT,tax_paid,cust_name,bal_Payment,adv_payment) tablespace TIDX

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this scenario like this...

```
CREATE TABLE test_table 
  ( id integer
  , corpId integer
  , paid_amt number(10,2)
  , incoming_date DATE );

ALTER TABLE test_table
add CONSTRAINT test_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

create index test_table_nui_1 on test_table(corpId);

create index test_table_nui_2 on test_table(incoming_date);

create sequence test_table_seq;

insert into test_table
  select test_table_seq.nextval
       ,MOD(test_table_seq.currval,6)
       ,MOD(test_table_seq.currval,10) + 1
       ,sysdate - MOD(test_table_seq.currval,200) 
  from all_objects, user_objects;
```

The cartesian join between all_objects and user_objects is just a hack to get a load of records inserted quickly. (657,000 rows in this case)

Running through the selects first all 657,000...

```
select sum(paid_amt)
from test_table;
```

Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 621  Bytes: 13  Cardinality: 1
    2 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 13  Cardinality: 1
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE DAVE.TEST_TABLE Cost: 621  Bytes: 9,923,914  Cardinality: 763,378

Then 109,650 for one corpId...

```
select sum(paid_amt)
from test_table
where corpId = 5;
```

Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 265  Bytes: 26  Cardinality: 1
    3 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 26  Cardinality: 1
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE DAVE.TEST_TABLE Cost: 265  Bytes: 3,310,138  Cardinality: 127,313
            1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX DAVE.TEST_TABLE_NUI_1 Cost: 213  Cardinality: 3,054

And finally 20,836 rows restricting by date...

```
SELECT sum(paid_amt) totalamount
FROM test_table e
WHERE  e.corpId = 5
AND e. incoming_date >= to_date('01-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
AND e. incoming_date <= to_date('09-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 265  Bytes: 35  Cardinality: 1
    3 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 35  Cardinality: 1
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE DAVE.TEST_TABLE Cost: 265  Bytes: 871,360  Cardinality: 24,896
            1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX DAVE.TEST_TABLE_NUI_1 Cost: 213  Cardinality: 3,054

All 3 queries were rapid (i.e. < 0.5 seconds)

An alternative would be to drop nui_1 and nui_2 and create a combined index on both columns. This then ran in 31ms on my db

```
create index test_table_nui_3 on test_table(corpId, incoming_date);
```

Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 15  Bytes: 35  Cardinality: 1
    3 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 35  Cardinality: 1
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE DAVE.TEST_TABLE Cost: 15  Bytes: 871,360  Cardinality: 24,896
            1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX DAVE.TEST_TABLE_NUI_3 Cost: 3  Cardinality: 14

This suggests that the aggregate function is not the problem, but your indexing may be. The best thing to do would be to check your explain plans.

Comment: I already have a composite index on (corpId, incoming_date). The problem is test_table itself has 319,332,896 records. The where clause I have specified fetches 64k records(used a count(*)) which is fast(less than a sec) due to the composite index. Calculating the sum(paid_amt) for this 64k records takes a long time.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise the table was so big.

Comment: You could consider partitioning on corp_id and/or date, or you could use a materialized view. A MV brought down my example to only 15ms even after I doubled the number of rows.